# Nokia here maps-api map overlay

Tags: javascript, here-api

So I'm working on a scenario were I need to have a floorplan as an overlay on top of a Nokia map, and I have succeeded in getting the image on top of the map, the problem is that I don't seem to be able to move it as I need to fit perfectly on a specific building. What am I doing wrong/missing? Is there any why to make it even more precise?

```
$(function(){
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);
    $('#knapp').click(function(){
    overlayFloorplan(map);
});

function overlayFloorplan(map) {

  var tileProvider = new H.map.provider.ImageTileProvider({

    min: 14,
    max: 17,

    getURL: function (column, row, zoom) {
      if (((zoom == 14) && (row < 4742 || column < 8880 || row > 4746 || column > 8884)) || 
        ((zoom == 15) &&  (row < 9484 || column < 17760 || row > 9492 || column > 17768)) ||
        ((zoom == 16) && (row < 18968 || column < 35520 || row > 18984 || column > 35536)) ||
        ((zoom  == 17) && (row < 37936 || column < 71040 || row > 37968 || column > 71072))) {
        console.log('BLANK');
        return //picture location
      } else {
        return //picture location
      }
    }
  });

  var overlayLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(tileProvider, {
    opacity: 0.5,
  });

  map.addLayer(overlayLayer);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing an image for the floor plan of a building on click can be handled by creating a marker at the building specific location that is invisible and handling the click event.  When click the event occurs the image can be displayed as a infobubble.  The location of the marker will be specific to the latitude and longitude of the location and the marker can be adjusted if necessary using the anchor offset.

[Using SVG markers with images](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers)